# Title-case words in string that are only bordered by whitespace (or start/end of string)

Tags: php, string, case, title-case

I need to apply title-casing to my string, but with some exceptions.

If the substring is separated by spaces and contains only letters, make the first letter uppercase and the rest lowercase.

If there are letters and non-letters, they should remain unchanged:

```
ucwords(strtolower("NEW APPLE IPHONE X 64GB CVX-Dk46"))
```

For example:
`NEW APPLE IPHONE X 64GB CVX-Dk46`

Should become:
`New Apple Iphone X 64GB CVX-Dk46`

Answer (score 2):

This will loop through each word and see if there is a digit in the word, if no then do the strtolower and ucwords.

```
$str = "NEW APPLE IPHONE X 64GB CVX-Dk46";

$arr = explode(" ", $str); // make it array

foreach($arr as &$word){ // loop array
    if(!preg_match("/\d/", $word)){ // is there not a digit in the word
        $word = ucwords(strtolower($word));
    }
}

echo implode(" ", $arr); // implode array to string
//New Apple Iphone X 64GB CVX-Dk46
```

https://3v4l.org/qccG9

Answer (score 1):

Here is another method.  The only difference is the use of the `array_walk()` function instead of the `foreach()` loop in Andreas' answer. (Which is also a good answer.)

```
$str = 'NEW APPLE IPHONE X 64GB CVX-Dk46';

$data = explode(' ', $str); //This will take the sting and break the string up
//into an array using the space bewtween the words to break apart the string.

array_walk($data, function(&$item){  //Walk each item in the array through a function to decide what gets UC letter.

  if(!preg_match('/\d/', $item)){ //Test for any numbers in a word.

    //If there are no numbers convert each character to lower case then upper case the first letter.
    $item = ucwords(strtolower($item));

  }

});

$newString = implode(' ', $data);  //Take the new array and convert it back to a string.

echo $newString; //This will output:  "New Apple Iphone X 64GB CVX-Dk46"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can not achieve this with a single line.Please see the below code if it can be helpful for you.

```
$val = "NEW APPLE IPHONE X 64GB CVX-Dk46";
$val = explode(" ", $val);
$finalString = '';
foreach ($val as $value) {
 if(preg_match('/^[a-zA-Z]+[a-zA-Z0-9._]+$/', $value)) { 
   $finalString = $finalString . " " . ucwords(strtolower($value));
 } else {
 $finalString = $finalString . " " . $value;
 }
}
echo $finalString;
```

Output will be as below:-

```
New Apple Iphone X 64GB CVX-Dk46
```

Comment: Au contraire, it **can** be written as a one-liner.  https://stackoverflow.com/a/68771787/2943403

Answer (score 0):

first of all you need to find the number in your string
 - if have the number you need to separate your string to array
the first array is contain only  string , the second array is contain number(or number and string)
 - if have not the number you need to use php function  strtolower to lower your string and use php function ucwords to converts the first character of a string to uppercase
 you can try the code below:
Link: https://3v4l.org/jW6Wf

```html
function upperCaseString($string)
{
$pattern = '/(?=\d)/';
$array = preg_split($pattern, $string, 2);
$text='';
 if(count($array)>1)
 {
  
  $text=ucwords(strtolower($array[0])).' '.strtoupper($array[1]);
 }
 else
 {
  $text=ucwords(strtolower($array[0]));
 }
 return $text;
}
$str = "NEW APPLE IPHONE X 64GB CVX-Dk46";
echo upperCaseString($str);
```

Comment: Please do not use StackSnippet formatting unless your snippet is runnable client-side.  Standard code formatting is less bloated/busy.

Answer (score 0):

For your sample string, this can be achieved with **a single matched substring** within a `preg_replace_callback()` call!

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/2nQmbO)) ([Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/GqYwPI/1))

```
echo preg_replace_callback(
         '~(?:\G ?)\p{Lu}+(?= |$)~u',
         function($m) {
             return mb_convert_case($m[0], MB_CASE_TITLE);
         },
         'NEW APPLE IPHONE X 64GB CVX-Dk46'
     );
// New Apple Iphone X 64GB CVX-Dk46
```

The `\G` (continue metacharacter) starts matching from the start of the string OR from where the pattern previously stopped matching.  I am using spaces and anchors to satisfy the requirement of matching whole ALL-CAPS words.

This performs better than nested lookarounds. e.g. `(?:(?:^| )\p{Lu}+(?= |$))+`